# Zend passing data from action in controller to view in another controler

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view, zend-controller

How can I pass data from action in controller to view in another controller?
From action in controler to view in the same controller is easy:
I simply write in action's function :

```
$this->view->assign('error', 'Wrong login');
```

and in view I recieve it in this way:

```
<?=$this->escape($this->error);?>
```

but how can I do it to receive it in view of another controller?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but my guess is that for every request there is only one Zend_View, so if you set something on ControllerA and forward execution to ControllerB you could access that data in the same way.

It´ll not work if you use the action helper _redirect because it´s a browser redirection, to just forward execution to another "place" use the _forward helper instead.

Another option is the flashMessenger helper, that a look at the docs

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html